# pandas not condition with filtering

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How I can implement not condition on the filtering

```
grouped = store_ids_with_visits.groupby(level=[0, 1, 2])
grouped.filter(lambda x: (len(x) == 1 and x['template_fk'] == exterior_template))
```

I want to get all entries that not answering on the condition

I tried doing:

```
grouped.filter(lambda x: ~(len(x) == 1 and x['template_fk'] == exterior_template))
```

But got following error:

```
filter function returned a int, but expected a scalar bool
```

Comment: Try replacing `~` (the bitwise NOT operator) with `not` -- e.g. `not (len(x)...`

Comment: @jedwards with this I got  'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous'.

Comment: Use `any` or `all` builtin functions on your array

Answer (score 20, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) to check for bool conditions and take only the `NOT(~)` values of the grouped dataframe:

```
 df[~df.isin(grouped.filter(lambda x: (len(x) == 1 and x['template_fk'] == exterior_template)))]
```